# HTML Emails Outlook breaking image URL

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to code up some HTML emails. I am getting really frustrated because Outlook seems to be breaking the image src URL up...

```
<img src="https://clientdeva.anpac.info/webquotes/content/images/FollowUpEmail/anico_logo." png="" alt="anico logo" class="logo" width="100px" height="100px">
```

it literally separates the png into its own attribute. No matter what I do I cannot get the thing to stay. I've tried hardcoding the URL into the HTML template.. i've tried passing the full image tag with the src as a parameter to be replaced in the stringified template. Nothing is working. Not to mention Outlook is a PITA to work with in general. Does anyone have any idea what I can do?

the creation of the url :

```
string anicoLogo = $"{baseUrl}webquotes/content/images/FollowUpEmail/anico_logo.png";
```

HTML:

```
<img src={logo} alt="anico logo" class="logo" width="100px" height="100px"/>
```

Comment: Please show the code that generates the email. Can you prove this works correctly and gives a correct result on other email clients?

Comment: what does your original code look like and what does the after look like.

Comment: if i have to bet you are missing a closing quote at the end of the file name. Show us the code that is generating this string

Comment: updated post with what yall asked for